# (with fspy)Why does the transparent plane show system checkerboard pattern after rendering

Tags: transparency

I used an empty transparent plane for shadows of the objects, but somehow the default checkerboard pattern is shown both in view port and in the pre-render view after I pressed <kbd>F12</kbd>.
I used two cameras for the scene. One is the camera setting I got from the addon fspy, the other is the actual camera that I want for the final picture. The checker on the plane disappears only when I set the fspy camera as active, and only in the view port. The plane is not checkered but a twisted pattern in viewport, definitely not the pattern under it. And it is still the checkered pattern after rendering.

view port of fspy as the active camera
[image]
render view of fspy as the active camera
[image]
render view of the actual camera
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello ! I suggest you read the manual parts about shadow catcher https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/object_settings/object_data.html the checkered pattern simply illustrates that this part of the image is transparent. You're supposed to composite it over another image